# Создание баркода в android

Tags: java, android, штрихкод, barcode

Как сгенерировать баркод и сохранить его в png (кодом). Все упирается в невозможность использования BufferedImage в android. Баркод необходим в формате EAN13.

Comment: Если можно использовать готовые решения, то В андроид арсенале есть куча библиотек этой темы, там есть и те которые генерируют штрих коды и we коды. Ну или можно посмотреть там исходники и найти для себя решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можете перечислить 1-2 такие библиотеки?

Comment: Вот ссылка, там нужно посмотреть более подходящий https://android-arsenal.com/tag/11?sort=created